# Replace with empty string duplicate values selected columns csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have come across a perhaps very specific problem, I have the following data:

Input

| id | name | phone1 | phone2 | phone3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 3222430085 | 9983146924 | 1234567890 |
| 2 | Vanessa | 3222430085 | 9934254243 |  |
| 3 | Maria | 7861628239 | 7861628239 | 7861628239 |
| 4 | Oscar | 7861157888 | 3222430085 |  |
| 4 | Paul | 7151087912 | 5555555555 |  |
| 5 | Paul | 7151087912 | 5555555555 |  |

Expected output

| id | name | phone1 | phone2 | phone3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 3222430085 | 9983146924 | 1234567890 |
| 2 | Vanessa |  | 9934254243 |  |
| 3 | Maria | 7861628239 |  |  |
| 4 | Oscar | 7861157888 |  |  |
| 4 | Paul | 7151087912 | 5555555555 |  |
| 5 | Paul |  |  |  |

I pose the problem basically based on a couple of selected columns to eliminate the duplicate records that are found within them.

In this case selected `phone1`, `phone2` and `phone3`

I have managed with pandas to remove entire rows that are exactly the same or by selecting columns but with this case I have not been able to solve it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Filter` the `phone` like columns then `stack` to reshape into a multiindex series, then drop duplicates in the series then `unstack` and `assign` the result back to original dataframe

```
df.assign(**df.filter(like='phone').stack().drop_duplicates().unstack())
```

---

```
  id     name      phone1      phone2      phone3
0  1     John  3222430085  9983146924  1234567890
1  2  Vanessa         NaN  9934254243         NaN
2  3    Maria  7861628239         NaN         NaN
3  4    Oscar  7861157888         NaN         NaN
4  4     Paul  7151087912  5555555555         NaN
5  5     Paul         NaN         NaN         NaN
```